# Detecting gestures using a service without interfering with other apps

Tags: java, android, service, gesture

I'm trying to create an app that detects gestures in the background like on the home screen or any other app.

For example, when you swipe down with 3 fingers on your home screen, it should take a screenshot.

I have been searching for answers but couldn't find any. Just to be clear, I don't want anything to be on the screen at all times, the user should not be able to see anything else than their home screen but when they swipe down with three fingers, it will take a screenshot.

I found similar kinds of questions with some solutions but they interfered with other apps : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910982/how-can-one-detect-screen-gestures-outside-ones-own-app)

This question is almost identical to mine: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830532/detect-gestures-without-blocking-other-apps)

Comment: In general it isn't possible.  You can make an overlay window and capture gestures on it, but taps won't be passed through under any circumstance.  It would be a huge security hole if this could be done-  in general android  does NOT allow direct key or touch events to be sent between apps.  To get this to work you'd need root at the least, if not a custom version of the OS.

Comment: If you wanted it to just happen on the homescreen you could always write your own launcher app (replacing the homescreen).  But that's a fair amount of work.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for answering! I thought something like this would be simple but I was wrong. I get why android doesn't allow this to happen. I will not spend any more time on finding a solution because I think what I want is impossible. Again, thanks for telling me.